# Pass shell variable to mongodb script

Tags: mongodb, shell, jenkins

I am using jenkins and mongodb on centos 7 server.
I want to insert some jenkins build data on success to my mongo database.
this is the code i'm running in my post build task shell:

```
echo 'password' | su -

mongo jenkinsdb <<\EOF
db.history.insert({wokspace:$WORKSPACE,remote_url:$GIT_URL,branch:$GIT_BRANCH,type:"back",date:$(date 
'+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),description:$short_description})


db.history.find()
EOF
```

The problem is mongo is interpreting the Jenkins environnement variables as in simple strings.
How can i pass those variables to the mongo script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preventing the variable interpolation by using `\` before `EOF`. See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html:

> Quoting or escaping the "limit string" at the head of a here document disables parameter substitution within its body. The reason for this is that quoting/escaping the limit string effectively escapes the $, `, and \ special characters, and causes them to be interpreted literally.

```
serene% a=1

serene% cat <<T
heredoc> $a
heredoc> T
1

serene% cat <<\T
heredoc> $a
heredoc> T
$a
```

Remove the backslash if you want interpolation to happen.

Comment: how about this query "mongo jenkinsdb --quiet --eval 'db.projects.find({name:$JOB_BASE_NAME})' > project_id.json" it gives me error